# why is 'google' keyword undefined?

Tags: reactjs, google-oauth

Im using Google OAuth for authentication in my App and I'm using the following script in my index.html:

```
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
```

Which is the gsi client of the API.

This is my App.js

```
import './App.css';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { googleLogout, GoogleOAuthProvider } from '@react-oauth/google';
import LoginBtn from './components/atoms/LoginBtn';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';


function App() {
  const [ user, setUser ] = useState({}) //Store my user data

  function handleCallbackResponse(response){
    console.log(response)
    var userData = jwtDecode(response.credential);
    console.log(userData);
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
    google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: '**************************.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      callback: handleCallbackResponse
    })
  }, []);

  return (

    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId="*************************.apps.googleusercontent.com">
      <div className="App">
        <LoginBtn />
      </div>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to do a callback function to store different Data but I cannot access global google functions because im getting:

```
'google' is undefined
```

Comment: You can't add script that way and access global google variable. Please follow the proper documentation for Google OAuth with React.

Answer (score 0):

use 'window' before any global function like

`window.google.accounts......`